# Left-continuous function defined on measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathbb{R}$ that assigns a finite non-negative number to each compact set. Show that there exists a left-continuous function $f$ such that for $-\infty<a<b<\infty$, we have $$\mu((a,b))=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}(f(b-\epsilon)-f(a+\epsilon))$$ (Note: Left-continuous means that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a^-}f(x)=f(a)$.)

If we assume the function $f$ is left-continuous, we have that $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}f(b-\epsilon)=f(b)$. So we need $f$ such that $\mu((a,b))=f(b)-\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}f(a+\epsilon)$. How can I choose the value of $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f(x) = \begin{cases} -\mu [x,0), & x<0 \\ 0, & x=0 \\
\mu[0,x), & x>0 \end{cases}$. Then it is easy to show that $\mu[a,b) = f(b)-f(a)$.

Left continuity of $f$ follows from the fact that $\lim_{b_n \uparrow b} \mu[a,b_n) = \mu [a,b)$.

Comment: I think your example is not left-continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: @JJBeck: Thanks for catching that. I think it is correct now.